# Why is Wilfred a fan of Matt Damon?

Tags: analysis, wilfred

In the US version of [*Wilfred*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1703925/) it is established right at the beginning and a recurring theme that Wilfred is a big fan of Matt Damon, yet I don't think it is ever explained why. Furthermore the 1st episode of the 2nd season makes an amazing reference to *Good Will Hunting* in one of the best scenes of the show (and maybe there are more references to Matt Damon movies I haven't recognized).

**Is there any reason or explanation why Wilfred is such a big Matt Damon fan?** I'd be interested in both in-universe explanations (if any, maybe there's something about him attractive to dogs?) as well as explanations from a writer's standpoint of why in particular Matt Damon was chosen and if there is any further meaning to this.

(But maybe it was just an arbitrary decision and there isn't much more to it. If relevant, I haven't seen much of the 2nd season and further yet, but don't fear spoilers either.)

Comment: What would you consider an acceptable reason to like an actor? I mean, I couldn't list any specific reasons that I like my favourite actors besides "I like their films/roles".

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat One that is referencing any sources, be that the TV show, or external sources. Of course I don't want to know why *you* like *Matt Damon*. ;-)

Comment: no, what I meant is regarding an in-universe explanation, what other answer can *anyone* give for liking an actor?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Well, the out-of-universe stuff is the more interesting anyway. And like I said, maybe the series gave some weird in.universe explanation, like dogs generally having a thing for *Damon* or *Wilfred* having some speicific important experience with him or one of his movies. Afterall there are millions of possible interesting in-universe answers (even if it's likely that the show is reluctant to give one, but who knows).

Comment: It might just be a funny name (perhaps because sounds vaguely like cursing).  It's also used as a running joke in the movie Team America, and is repeatedly said in Sarah Silverman's comic song about "f---ing Matt Damon."

Comment: Shouldn't the question be "Why does Ryan think that Wilfred's favourite actor is Matt Damon"?

Comment: @ChrisDafnis That only holds *if* Wilfred is ultimately a product of Ryan's imagination. If *that*'s why, then an answer is free to argue that. But it's a premise that's largely irrelevant for the general *question* and would have imposed an unnecessary limitation to it.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree with Professor_Feather on that one. It is almost assuredly the same joke or similar to that of Team America. And lets not forget that Wilfred is a dog. So, it stands to reason that his sense of perspective might be a little skewed or even not very well informed based on his life experience. So his opinion that Matt Damon is the greatest actor is the equivalent to us thinking Tom Hanks or Robert Deniro is the greatest actor. Especially given when the show was aired, Matt Damon was mostly known for his 50/50 shot movies, and the Bourne action thrillers. No offense to his more recent Oscar contending films.

Comment: Please backup your answer with something to indicate this may be the case. As it stands this is more of a comment, and M&TV isn't a discussion forum.

Answer (score -1):

It was originally a joke in the Australian series. I’m not sure why they picked Matt Damon, maybe they wanted some that sounded similar to matamon or maybe that’s why they made up that name.

Comment: This is very very thin, please [edit] in sources to back up your answer, otherwise this looks like unsourced (and not educated enough) speculation.

Answer (score -8):

I think its an inside, like maybe Matt Damon turned down the role of Wilfred or something but other than the Madamon I cant think of any significant importance Matt has had in the show.

Comment: Please backup your answer with something to indicate this may be the case. As it stands this is more of a comment, and M&TV isn't a discussion forum.